# Spring Data Neo4j java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm new with spring data neeo4j. I'm trying to test a node but when I run the test an error associated with java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException happened.

This is my configuration:

application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>

    <context:spring-configured/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.glx.partycore">
        <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

applicationContext-neo4j.xml

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.2.xsd">

    <neo4j:repositories base-package="com.glx.partycore.repository"/>

<!--     <tx:annotation-driven /> -->
        <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

        <bean class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase" id="graphDatabaseService">
            <constructor-arg  index="0" value="${neo4j.server}"/>
<!--             <constructor-arg index="1" value="${neo4j.username}"/> -->
<!--             <constructor-arg index="2" value="${neo4j.password}"/> -->
        </bean>

        <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" base-package="com.glx.partycore.repository"/>

 <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>
</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
    <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <roo.version>1.2.5.RELEASE</roo.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
...
<!-- Neo dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-rest-graphdb</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-dsl</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Continent.java

```
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.index.IndexType;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.RooJavaBean;

@NodeEntity
@RooJavaBean
public class Continent extends AbstractEntity {

    @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT)
    private String code;
    @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT)
    private String name;

}
```

ContinentRepository.java

```
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;

import com.glx.partycore.domain.Continent;

public interface ContinentRepository extends GraphRepository<Continent>{

}
```

And the error is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'continentRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.data.repository.query.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider] while setting bean property 'evaluationContextProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:279)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
.....
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:60)
```

It's looks like anything is wrong in my neo4j configuration because there is no error from the "node" spring data ... I don't know what could be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the project is working. I'm using the same code without spring roo and it's work. It's seems that spring roo has any conflict with Spring Data Neo4j.

I created an issue to Spring Project.